# Girl with no magic powers at a magic academy, then she gains powers

Tags: story-identification, anime, magic

This girl with no magic is at a magic academy. She fights another girl. A guy arrives. There was a balcony scene. He somehow gives her magic. She gains magic and fights again (I think) this time I think there was more people fighting with or against her.

There was a library scene. Then I remember a scene where there's people with mask seated on the side while they had to do something, I think like a task or something.

Comment: The elements you cite (magical girl, magic academy, library, masks) are quite common in animes. Consider having a look at the [_"How to ask a good anime Story-ID question" FAQ_](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11875/40711) to help you remember other details (when did you see this, where, peculiarity of the characters, ...) and then [edit] them in the question.

Comment: When and where did you see it? Was it a film or a series?

Answer (score 2):

**Little Witch Academia**

> "A believing heart is your magic!"—these were the words that Atsuko "Akko" Kagari's idol, the renowned witch Shiny Chariot, said to her during a magic performance years ago. Since then, Akko has lived by these words and aspired to be a witch just like Shiny Chariot, one that can make people smile. Hence, even her non-magical background does not stop her from enrolling in Luna Nova Magical Academy."
> [MyAnimelist.net](https://myanimelist.net/anime/33489/Little_Witch_Academia_TV/)

[image: Luna Nova Magic girls]